# Haskell import module

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use this module in my haskell code: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MissingH-1.0.0/docs/Data-String-Utils.html to use the function "replace" - However, when I try this code:

```
import Data.String.Utils
```

Haskell tells me there is no such module.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you installed the module via cabal? `cabal update; cabal install MissingH`

Comment: Hm I'm not sure I see what you mean, I'm running Haskell on Windows..

Answer (score 14):

You don't have the module installed, that's the problem. :) MissingH isn't distributed with the standard Haskell install -- it's a module you can install, but you have to download it first. `cabal`, the Haskell package installer (it is to Haskell what `easy_install` is to python or `cpan` is to Perl) will do that for you.

Follow the instructions at the [Cabal page for Windows](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cabal-Install#Windows). Once `cabal.exe` is installed, do

```
cabal.exe update
cabal.exe install MissingH
```

(`Data.String.Utils` is in the MissingH module.)

Comment: So, I downloaded the exe binary compiler for cabal (windows) and put it my \bin director of the "Haskell Platform folder", but WinHugs tells me there is no 'update' variable

Comment: By the way - the cabal release I downloaded is this http://www.haskell.org/cabal/release/cabal-install-1.18.0.2/cabal.exe @Cristian Ternus

Comment: Oh, you don't run it from within hugs. You run it from your terminal -- PowerShell or cmd.exe.

Comment: Hey @Cristian I have run the two commands from cmd.exe and I installed MissingH, however, when I run my code WinHug returns - ERROR file:.\ex.hs - Can't find imported module "Data.String.Utils"
Any ideas?