# Haskell Import MissingH

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to import the Data.String.Utils module in my Haskell code, this is part of the MissingH package. I've installed cabal and used it to acquire MissingH, which is properly installed. However, wehn I try adding

```
import Data.String.Utils
```

to my code, WinHugs returns

```
ERROR file:.\ex.hs - Can't find imported module "Data.String.Utils"
```

Any feedback?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Haskell import module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601789/haskell-import-module)

Comment: Just like last time you asked this question, you need to install the MissingH package to have access to the modules in that package.  Just like last time, the solution is to 1) install cabal-install 2) `cabal update` 3) `cabal install missingh`.

Comment: Hi, I did that, and cabal says all the required packages are installed, but then WinHugs still returns the same error. Sorry about the double-question, I thought that as I had already installed Cabal the other question has sort of "expired"

Comment: That's the problem - you are using hugs which, afaik, doesn't support packages.  You'll want to use ghc and ghci.

Comment: If you are used to WinHugs and are changing to ghc you might want to use WinGHCi, it comes with the Windows version of the Haskell Platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have MissingH installed with Cabal.

Using Cabal packages with WinHugs is hit and miss.

Use ghci and `import Data.String.Utils` should work.